# PHP domdocument is having unexpected value in end

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to parse simple html value, and remove an attribute with `foreach` loop, while the code works fine, but the `DOMDocument` or html string closing `</li>` tag for the first element is missing from the first item.

And the missing `</li>` tag for the first element is appearing in the last unexpectedly.

```
<?php 
//remove id attributes and print string
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$str_val = '
  <li class="nav-head">Salamandar</li>
    <li id="12" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">How to P</a></li>
    <li id="13" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">How to F</a></li>
    <li id="14" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Which Ca</a></li>
    <li id="17" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Types Sa</a></li>
    <li id="19" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Poiso Br</a></li>
    <li class="nav-header">Keeping Safe</li>
    <li id="21" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Keepchld</a></li>
    <li id="24" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Keepdogs</a></li>
    <li id="27" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">KeepRept</a></li>';
$dom->loadHTML($str_val, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$li_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li");

foreach($li_tags as $li_tag){
  if(!(($li_tag->getAttribute("class") == "nav-header") || ($li_tag->getAttribute("class") == "nav-head"))){
    $li_tag->removeAttribute("id");
  }
}

$str_markval = $dom->saveHTML();

echo $str_markval;

?>
```

The above getting the result:

```
<li class="nav-head">Salamandar
    <li class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">How to P</a></li>
    <li class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">How to F</a></li>
...
    <li class="nav-header">Keeping Safe</li>
...
    <li class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Keepdogs</a></li>
    <li class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">KeepRept</a></li></li>
```

As visible above, the above HTML for the first `<li>` is not closing, instead the closing `</li>` is appearing at the end.

Comment: If you don't have direct access to fix the `<li>`, wrap it in some unique element then remove on saveHTML https://3v4l.org/XWSjJ

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I actually have `<ul class=""></ul>` wrapped around the `li` stacks. I thought to remove them, as I am testing some Dom parsing. now I got this

Comment: eek sorry, I meant `ul` not `li`, yeah if you have them wrapped around it then there wouldn't be an issue https://3v4l.org/idhHj domdocument expects a root element

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a list of `li` without a containing `ul`, it's a DOM error described as `Element li not allowed as child of element body in this context`. Your PHP DOM parser is unable to work if the HTML is not valid.

You just need to wrap your HTML within an `ul` tag and then the rest of your code will work.

```
$str_val = '
<ul>
    <li class="nav-head">Salamandar</li>
    <li id="12" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">How to P</a></li>
    <li id="13" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">How to F</a></li>
    <li id="14" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Which Ca</a></li>
    <li id="17" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Types Sa</a></li>
    <li id="19" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Poiso Br</a></li>
    <li class="nav-header">Keeping Safe</li>
    <li id="21" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Keepchld</a></li>
    <li id="24" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">Keepdogs</a></li>
    <li id="27" class="natm"><a class="nlnk" href="#">KeepRept</a></li>
</ul>';
```

Comment: the original markup code actually have `<ul class=""></ul>` wrapped, actually I was testing PHP Dom parsing, so - I though - let's see the parsing, then in final code, I will enclose with `<ul class="">` `</ul>` - so I got the resolution.